# How to hide a primefaces layoutUnit if no content

Tags: jsf, layout, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I hide (rendered = false) a primefaces layoutUnit when there's no mention to the ui:insert, with ui:define?

ex.: I have a layout:

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <ui:insert name="centerPage" />
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit position="west">
    <ui:insert name="leftPage" />
</p:layoutUnit>
```

And I have a page that loads only centerPage, not leftPage:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/app/layout/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="centerPage">
...

</ui:define></ui:composition>
```

But when access this page, I can see a thin layoutunit west without content. I need to hide it.

Comment: Can't just set the style as border: 0px thin black; on the layout Unit

Comment: Use a different template?